# How to use a SearchView to filter a ListView in Xamarin Studio - Android

Tags: android, xamarin.android

*First let me be clear about this question, i am NOT looking for someone to the code for me. I am looking for something to guide me to the right direction.*

I have a small question regarding the `SearchView` within Xamarin Studio. I have made a small application that retrieves data from a server using a `HttpClient`. The data that i receive is put in a custom Adapter that i've made. The adapter is used to put the data witin the listview.

Now my question. I want to use the SearchView so the user can search for a specific item in the listview. But the only examples i've found were using a searchview in a actionbar. And i do not use the actionbar.

So really my question is:
How can i use a searchview without putting it in a action bar, and how do i filter the listview.
Can someone tell/show me how i can solve this, or were i should start.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have been looking for a clear tutorial also, could not find 1 that does not use the actionbar. What would be usefull is to use that specific tutorial and then look how you can remove the actionbar from the code. I could not find a solution for that. I've found this:  http://blog.ostebaronen.dk/2014/03/filtering-listview-with-searchview-in.html  But like i said it uses a actionbar. Maybe someone can tell us ow to use this without the actionbar

Comment: Yeah that could also be a solution.

Comment: Aside from using `ActionBar` to filter with `ISearchView`, you could add a header to your `ListView` that would contain an `EditText` field to filter your search. Similar to something like this. http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-edittext-filter.html  But fyi, since 3.0 using `SearchView` in an `ActionBar` is the preferred way to search in android.

Answer (score 0):

Searching **custom Listview** without (**IFilterable**) with simple **Linq** query 
Most simple might help you..
`

```
public class yourActivity : Activity, SearchView.IOnQueryTextListener
{

    ListView yourListView;
    List<CustomListView_Item_class> yourListViewItems= new List<CustomListView_Item_class>() {
            new CustomListView_Item_class{ CustomListView_Item_class.object1= "item1", CustomListView_Item_class.object2= "item2"},
        };
    SearchView yourSearchView;
    yourCustomListViewAdapterName yourCustomListViewAdapter;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create your application here
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);


        yourListView= FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.yourListView);
        yourSearchView= FindViewById<SearchView>(Resource.Id.yourSearchView);

        yourCustomListViewAdapter= new yourCustomListViewAdapterName (this, yourListViewItems);
        yourListView.Adapter = adapter;
        yourListView.TextFilterEnabled = false;
        setupSearchView();

    }

    private void setupSearchView()
    {
        yourSearchView.SetIconifiedByDefault(false);
        yourSearchView.SetOnQueryTextListener(this);
        yourSearchView.SubmitButtonEnabled = true;
        yourSearchView.SetQueryHint("Search");
    }

    public bool OnQueryTextChange(string newText)
    {
        try
        {
            if (TextUtils.IsEmpty(newText))
            {
                yourListView.ClearTextFilter();
                yourCustomListViewAdapter= new yourCustomListViewAdapterName (this, yourListViewItems);
                yourListView.Adapter = adapter;
            }
            else
            {

                QuesAnsList.ClearTextFilter();
                List<CustomListView_Item_class> yourListViewItems2= (from i in yourListViewItems
                                         where i.object1.ToLower().Contains(newText.ToLower())
                                         select i).ToList();
                yourCustomListViewAdapter= new yourCustomListViewAdapterName (this, yourListViewItems2);
                yourListView.Adapter = adapter;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, ex.Message.ToString(), ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }
        return true;
    }

    public bool OnQueryTextSubmit(string query)
    {
        return false;
    }
}`
```